# How to use a relative path for (jquery) ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function:

`$.post("/ajax.php",{query:data},function(result){...`

the location of `ajax.php` is in the root of my domain (i.e. site.com/ajax.php)

this same script gets called when the user is in a folder (i.e. site.com/m/)

The problem I face is that I want to reference the root directory. Usually `/file.php` refers to the home directory as opposed to `file.php`.

My requests are being sent to `http://site.com/m/ajax.php`.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: in javascript, when you reference `/` it takes the document root, not the server root. Store the server root in a variable and use that in your JS function call.

Comment: so you mean store `document.location.hostname` (or `<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_ROOT']?>`) and use that in an 'absolute' path?

Comment: seems like something is redirecting on server side

Comment: @iight that's correct, store the server root as a JS variable.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you for the idea and for clarifying! Feel free to write up an answer if you want to:)

Comment: Whoops! I thought @Ohgodwhy had said it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing as @Ohgodwhy suggested:

```
$.post(
        "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>`/ajax.php",
        {query:data},
        function(result){
        // alert(result);
        });
```

So far, it's working for me!

Comment: Yeah it worked for me too "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>. I am not sure how robust this solution is though?